# Need help in sequentialeExecution of Java Swing forms

Tags: java, swing

I need help in the running of the following Java program.
I want the main program to pause running after it displays a new `JFrame` form and resume after the new window is closed ( or Next button is clicked ) .

So The 10 Forms should come sequentially after I press the next button not altogether at once!

### MainClass.java

```
public class MainClass {
void Run()
{
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        new NewForm().setVisible(true);
}

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    new MainClass().Run();
}
}
```

### NewForm.java

```
public class NewForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public NewForm() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("Next");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(155, 155, 155)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(190, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(131, 131, 131)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(146, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }
   public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewForm().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;              
}
```

Comment: *"..after it displays a new JFrame"*  See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)   Use a modal dialog for frame 2, 3 ..N or a `CardLayout`.

Comment: http://jwizardcmponent.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Setting jframe visible will not wait until the jframe is closed, thats why 10 jframes pops at you. You need to display just one, then add a ActionLisetener to your button. In this action, you just close your panel and open onother one. Of coursce you will need some global counter, consider making i static for start.

Comment: Horrid advice.  Was looking questionable until the last sentence when you mentioned an entirely unnecessary use of static.